# Can someone explain what this graph travesal in Gremlin is doing?

Tags: gremlin

I'm having a bit of trouble understand these Gremlin queries:

```
from os import getenv
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
 pmap = g.V().has(name, value) \
                .union(__.hasLabel('UID'), 
                       __.hasLabel('OID').outE('attached').inV()) \
                .union(__.propertyMap(),
                       __.inE('attached').outV().hasLabel('OID') \
                                         .propertyMap()).toList()
```

So I understand `g.V().has(name, value) is looking for a vertex with the key`name = value`. What is the union doing here? Is it unioning vertices with a label "OID" with edges that go outward with a label "attached"? 
What is the`inV()` and why are the two arguments for union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `union()` step just merges the child traversal streams that are provided to it as arguments. Take a more simple example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').union(has('age',29),bothE())
==>v[1]
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').union(has('age',30),bothE())
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
```

In the first example, we get `union()` takes in a "marko" vertex as the starting point for both `has('age',29)` and `bothE()`. As `v[1]` also has a "age" property with a value of "29" we see `v[1]` in the output. We also see all the edges of `v[1]` in merged into that stream of output. In the second traversal, we see `v[1]` being filtered out as the "age" is not equal to "30" so all we get are the edges.

With that explanation in mind, consider what the traversal you've included in your question is doing. It finds a vertex with a "name" and some value for that key. That becomes the start point for the first `union()`. If the vertex has a label of "UID" then it pass through. If the vertex has a label of "OID" then it traverses the outgoing "attached" edges to the adjacent vertex and returns those.

What's odd about that is the fact that a `Vertex` can only have one label (at least by TinkerPop's definition - some graphs support multiple element labels). So, assuming one label, you really only get one or the other stream. Personally, I don't think the use of `union()` is a good choice there. I think it would be more intuitive to use coalesce since only one stream can be returned, thus expanding my example from above:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').coalesce(has('age',30),has('age',29).bothE())
==>e[9][1-created->3]
==>e[7][1-knows->2]
==>e[8][1-knows->4]
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').coalesce(has('age',29),has('age',29).bothE())
==>v[1]
```

The use of `coalesce()` makes the intent much more clear in my opinion. Following on further with the original code to the second `union()` - at this point, you either have the original `Vertex` or one or more "attached" vertices for which the traversal combines a `propertyMap()` and/or a `propertyMap()` of an additional "attached" vertices that have an "OID" label.

It's really hard to say exactly what the intent of this traversal is given the information provided. Depending on what the data structure is and what the intent is, I  imagine that things could be simplified. Hopefully, I've at least explained what `union()` is doing and clarified that for you as that seemed to be the core of your question.

Comment: I see so in your first example, union returns 4 things: a vertex (1) and 3 edges (9,7, 8) because union joins them all together? I see what you mean by "taking in" the marko vertex though.

Comment: So wait, I thought the first union argument means that if the vertex with the name and value ALSO hasLabel('UID'), return that. But does it also pass through to the next union argument: "hasLabel("OID").outE...? If the vertex just has a label "UID", will the vertex return?

Comment: Whatever comes out of the first `union()` becomes the input to the second `union()`.  So, in answer to your specific question here in the comment, if the vertex with the name/value also has a label of "UID" then it will become the input to the next `union()`.

Comment: I see, but the vertex going INTO The union is passed to all of the union arguments right?

Comment: it is the start object to each of the child traversals of `union()`. so the second `union()` should return a `propertyMap()` and if there are incoming "attached" edges for that vertex that satisfy the second child traversal, then it should return those as well.

Comment: And if the first union returns the vertex attached to the vertex with a label of OID, then it is passed to the second union. The second union then returns that vertex's propertyMap AND the propertyMaps of any vertexes attached to it with a label of OID right?

Comment: yes. i still think the use of `union()` here isn't a terribly intuitive way to learn about that step. I would recommend opening a Gremlin Console session and trying a few traversal with the toy graph and see what is being returned under different cases.